# Required installation of untrusted package

Tags: 14.04, package-management, update-manager

Today I was updating my Ubuntu software and suddenly a 'not possible to  update because package system is broken' error came up.

Somehow I try to follow from Ubuntu community in Google and something happens when I try to update using Software Updater. The 'required installation of untrusted package, this required installing packages from unauthenticated sources'.

I tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` from Google and the result is failed to fetch http://my.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease and many failed to fetch notifications.

Please help me because I'm new and I don't know how to fix it. Also my Ubuntu cannot connect to internet.

Comment: What's the complete, verbatim output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Code:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Post back the errors, if any, from the 'apt-get update' output.

If there are no errors are reported then you are good to run:

Code:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(The above command does NOT upgrade to next ubuntu version, it just does some smart upgrades to the present system).